# Український еквівалент для слова "заблуждение"

Tags: переклад, from-russian

Надайте, будь ласка, український еквівалент для російського слова "заблуждение" (англ. delusion)

Прошу врахувати, що слово "помилка", яке надають деякі джерела, позначає одноразову хибну дію або результат такої дії, в той час як потрібне мені слово має описувати постійний стан мислення, що характеризується викривленим уявленням про реальність.

Comment: Мені подобається [***хибна](http://sum.in.ua/s/khybnyj) думка*** або [***упередження***](http://sum.in.ua/s/uperedzhennja). Вони якісь стилістично нейтральні, я б сказала.

Comment: @OksanaGubrenko, плюсую за «упередження». Хоча воно є дослівним перекладом рос. «предубеждение» (а не «заблуждение»), але стилістично і за практичним контекстом застосування досить близьке. А якщо потрібна 100% семантична точність — то тоді вже «хибна думка».

Comment: @Sasha, я усвідомлюю, що  *упередження* - точний відповідник російського *предубеждение*. Але відповідно до СУМ перше значення *упередження* не має саме негативного віддітнку. Також я розумію, що більшість словників пропонує *оману* й *облуду*. Та як на мене, вони доречні саме у складі сталих виразів *вводить/впадать в заблуждение* тощо. А от як окремі іменники і в нейтральному контексті вони мені звучать дещо дивно. На противагу *хибній думці* і *упередженню*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Дійшов висновку, що найточніше змістові слова "заблуждение" відповідають в різних ситуаціях "омана" і "упередження".

Коли слово є частиною сталих виразів - омана:

> вводити в оману
>
> перебувати в омані

Коли слово є самостійною семантичною одиницею - упередження:

> "це дуже небезпечне упередження"

Comment: Гляньте, будь ласка, мою відповідь щодо *вводити в*

Comment: Я її бачив. Але з власного мовного досвіду, навіть невеликого, знаю, що вислів "вводити в оману" дійсно вживається і точно не є мертвим, як чомусь вважає пан Караванський. Крім того, він є стилістично нейтральним, як зазначив @Artemix

Answer (score 10):

[Російсько-український словник сталих виразів](http://stalivyrazy.org.ua/everyfile2.php?transfer=folders/ze/zabluzdjnij.html) пропонує два слова: ***облуда*** і ***омана***.

> - Быть, находиться, пребывать в заблуждении.
>     *Бути в **облуді** (в **омані**); помилятися; блудити.*
> - Вводить, ввести в заблуждение кого.
>     *Заводити, завести у помилку (в оману) кого; призводити, призвести до помилки (до облуди) кого; збивати, збити на помилку кого; упроваджувати, упровадити у блуд кого; ошукувати, ошукати (іноді омиляти, омилити) кого; на хибний шлях ставати, поставити кого; збивати, збити з правдивого шляху кого; дурити, піддурити (здурити) кого.*
> - Впадать, впасть в заблуждение.
>     *Помилятися, помилитися; западати, запасти в облуду (в оману, іноді в блуд).*

Comment: [Worldwidedictionary](https://uk.worldwidedictionary.org/%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0) дає ще декілька цікавих синонімів до омани, серед яких є МАНА́, яку напускають: "Та то ману тілько пускають. Знаємо ми,— твердили перші (Панас Мирний)". Оману також можна напустити: "Та хтось зумисне покопирсав ломакою, щоб напустити на нас оману,— сказала Гризельда, придивляючись до слідів (І. Нечуй-Левицький)".

Answer (score 5):

Хоча це саме про зворот *вводить в заблуждение*, та все ж:

Святослав Караванський, *[Пошук українського слова або боротьба за національне "Я"](http://maidan.org.ua/files/karavan/P1.HTM) (Науково-популярні бесіди на мовні теми з додатком словничків-рятівничків від моди та мавпування)*

> Гляньмо на ще одну ідіому, зафіксовану в усіх словниках: *уводити в
>   оману кого.*
>
> Це українізована копія російського виразу вводить в заблуждение.  Жива
>   мова не знає такого звороту.  Чи мусимо ми вдаватися до такої кальки,
>   чи ми маємо можливість обходитися без неї?
>
> Чи ж наші лексичні одиниці
>
> - забивати баки кому
> - замилювати очі кому
> - збивати з пантелику кого
> - наводити полуду на очі кому
> - заводити на манівці кого
>
> і багато інших не годні заступити кальки вводити в оману?

---

### Чтиво

Ось цікаве обговорення на форумі slovnyk.ua - ["Заблуждение".](http://forum.slovnyk.ua/lofiversion/index.php?t640.html)

Comment: Наведені приклади мають певне стилістичне забарвлення. Я не можу уявити щоб (умовно) Папа Римський сказав кардиналу "Ви мені баки забиваєте" замість "Ви вводите мене в оману".

Comment: @Artemix А якщо "Ви мене зводите на манівці" чи "збиваєте з пантелику", чи "замилюєте мені очі"?

Comment: Точно не скажу, бо не відчуваю їх стилістичного забарвлення, хоча мені здається що у такій розмові вони також додають експресії, яка може бути не бажаною.

Answer (score 0):

Омана, облуда. 
Упередження - інша річ. Упередження - завчасно сформована негативна думка про когось чи щось. Наприклад, наговорили тобі поганих пліток про людину, ти ще знаєш її, а вже вважаєш поганою - ти упереджений до неї. А заблуждения - це більше помилки, вони можуть бути і позитивними, і негативними.

Comment: Ласкаво просимо до сайту Ukrainian Language.SE! Наші критерії якості дещо відрізняються від того, що можна побачити на мовних форумах і блоґах. Необґрунтовані відповіді базуються лише на думці їхнього автора і тому викликають хвилю диспутів і заперечень. А якісні відповіді ґрунтуються на якісних джерелах: словниках, поважних сайтах тощо. Будь ласка, перегляньте сторінки [tour], [answer] а також [«Якими мають бути гарні відповіді»](http://meta.ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/5/). Ви завжди можете виправити відповідь, зробивши її більш аргументованою. Для цього натисніть [edit].